# How can I add Dark Mode styles in an addComponent function TailwindCSS

Tags: plugins, components, tailwind-css, darkmode

I am making some button components, but I need a way to implement Dark Mode. I know that adding styles for hover, focus, etc. states can be added like in the example below. How would I go about doing this for dark mode? How can I display the button differently when Dark Mode is enabled.

```js
addComponents({
  '.button': {
    padding: '.5rem 1rem',
    borderRadius: '.25rem',
    fontWeight: '600',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
    '&:dark': { /* something like this? */
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dark mode in TailwindCSS is not so simple feature to replicate with plain CSS. By default it [based](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode) on `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)`. You may pass media variants into component

```js
addComponents({
    '.button': {
        padding: '.5rem 1rem',
        borderRadius: '.25rem',
        fontWeight: '600',
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
        },

        // media strategy
        '@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)': {
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
        }
    }
})
```

It will work unless user specifies its [strategy](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually) as `class`. So you need to add this case as another component - `.dark <your-component>`

```js
addComponents({
    '.button': {
        padding: '.5rem 1rem',
        borderRadius: '.25rem',
        fontWeight: '600',
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
        },

        // media strategy
        '@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)': {
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
        },
    },

    // class strategy
    '.dark .button': {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
    }
})
```

But it can fail too - user can specify **ANY** [selector](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#customizing-the-class-name) as a base for darkmode

This is where `dark:` variant can be helpful - it do the job for you defining which type of selector user specified. However you still need to make two components (`button` and `button-dark`) and use it like

```html
<button class="button dark:button-dark"></button>
```

Which is not user friendly

But what you can do (and this is not mentioned in the docs - at least I didn't found, but I can see a [test](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/tests/apply.test.js#L1387) in source code named "should be possible to use apply in plugins") - is to [pass](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply) `@apply` as key and empty object as a value. You can rewrite whole component with `@apply` or combine both CSS and Tailwind features

```js
addComponents({
    '.button': {
        padding: '.5rem 1rem',
        borderRadius: '.25rem',
        fontWeight: '600',
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
        },

        // dark mode
        '@apply dark:bg-blue-500 dark:hover:text-white': {},
    },
})
```

Now dark mode will work no matter the strategy

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/qhjc2guFhw) - switch dark mode in a browser developer tools (or use `darkMode: 'class'` and add `.dark` to a wrapper)

Comment: This does feel somewhat hacky, but hey it works. Marked as solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of tailwind classes like this to use `dark` utility :

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="p-4">
  <button class="py-2 px-4 rounded font-semibold bg-slate-300 hover:bg-red-500 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:text-white ">Click me</button>
</div>
```

[Tailwind play link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/jaQ9bE3dby)

Here the dark mode is chosen by Operating system preference. But you can also build sites that support toggling dark mode manually using the `class` strategy.

If you want to support toggling dark mode manually instead of relying on the operating system preference , you can visit [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually)

Comment: I think I have been a bit unclear in my explanation, my apologies. I understand how dark mode works, but how would I go about adding those `dark:text-white` properties to the component object in JavaScript.